# Cannot set swap, backup, and viminfo in vimrc (win64)

Tags: vim

Folks:
I have searched stackoverflow and other databases for the answer to this.  I thought that a number of threads would have resolved it by now, but without luck.

I have attempted to set all three of these parameters using

```
set dir = c:\\tmp
set bdir = c:\\tmp
set viminfo +=nc:\\tmp\\viminfo
```

I thought that perhaps the name of the file was incorrect. I tried them in a newly created vimrc, _vimrc, and .vimrc (+ gvimrc...) in my $VIM (I don't want any of these files in the working directory, or in $HOME).  These attempts did not work-- checking settings showed that after starting vim after these vimrc changes were made did not affect the settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spaces around the equals sign. The spaces are not part of the syntax for set and set thinks you are sending in 3 parameters instead of one.

The commands below should work.

```
set dir=c:\\tmp
set bdir=c:\\tmp
set viminfo+=nc:\\tmp\\viminfo
```

Also the proper place for these commands are in your vimrc file which would be located at `$HOME/_vimrc`

Comment: It should be _vimrc if you are on windows. Also you can edit the file by typing `:e $MYVIMRC` from inside of vim.

Comment: I don't want vimrc in my $HOME.  I want it in a separate directory.  I tried the :e command-- it did not recognize the already existing file (which was not in $HOME).

Comment: You could edit the system vimrc file. To find out where the system vimrc file is located type `:version`

Comment: The system vimrc file is $VIM/vimrc (where I want it).  The user vimrc file is $HOME/_vimrc (where I don't want it).  I don't always have access to the $HOME directory (a network drive that I have access to when connected to a VPN).

Comment: Maybe the issue is how to set $HOME only for vim?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use something like this which worked well:

```
set backup
set backupdir=$VIMRUNTIME/temp//
set directory=$VIMRUNTIME/temp//
```

Try forward slashes?